# What does it mean he that spared not his own son Romans 8:32

Tags: romans

He that spared not his own Son, but delivered him up for us all, how shall he not with him also freely give us all things?

Comment: John 3:16 "For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life."

Answer (score 3):

He references the Father. If the Father is willing to give up his son for us (by sacrifice on the cross), then he is willing to give everything to us. The verse highlights the love of the Father for us, lost children of the world. v38 is a fitting conclusion:

> "For I am sure that neither death nor life, nor angels nor rulers, nor
>   things present nor things to come, nor powers, nor height nor
>   depth, nor anything else in all creation, will be able to separate us
>   from the love of God in Christ Jesus our Lord."

Commentary from [Precept Austin](http://www.preceptaustin.org/romans_831-33):

> He who so freely gave the choicest thing that he had to give when we
>   were yet helpless, ungodly, sinners and enemies of God (Ro 5:6, 8,
>   10-see notes Romans 5:6; 5:8; 5:10) -- now that we are His friends --
>   will He not complete the process (Php 1:6-note)?